# ivy: resolve only compatible release with version range

Tags: ivy, dependency-management

I have a common component that is under constant development. many projects depend on this component. Right now, i use rev="latest.release" for the dependency. But that might break the build, consider releasing an incompatible 2.0 of the component. What I want to express is: use the latest release that is a patch level.

So instead of "latest.release", I would write "[1.1,1.2[", but that also resolves the latest integration builds (like 1.1.9_dev1). Is there a way to combine version range and status?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690787/how-to-use-ivy-integration-versions-against-old-versions-of-code/11696538#11696538 and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696831/overriding-an-ivy-dependencies-revision/3704998#3704998

Answer (score 1):

Ivy doesn't support a dependency like this:

```
<dependency org="org.acme" name="common" rev="[1.1,1.2[" status="release" />
```

But it support extra attributes, so you could write something like:

```
<dependency org="org.acme" name="common" rev="[1.1,1.2[" e:mystatus="release" />
```

See: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#extra

The check for the extra attribute is about equality, whereas the Ivy status is a comparaison (release > integration). In your use case about only "release", it should work the same.

But then it would require to you to spread the e:mystatus to every module you have in your Ivy repository, which can be a pain, depending on how much you control your Ivy repository.